# Next pages not working in bs4 and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

I'm trying to get output from all of the `next pages` using `BeautifulSoup`, `CSS` selectors and Pandas `DataFrame` but getting only the first page as output. Can you help me?
Thanks.

CODE:

```
import requests 
import bs4
import pandas as pd
base_url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com'
res = requests.get("http://quotes.toscrape.com/") 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml') 

all_quote = []
all_author = []
all_tag = []

for element in soup.select('.quote'):
    quote = element.select_one('span.text').text
    all_quote.append(quote)
    
    author = element.select_one('small.author').text
    all_author.append(author)
    
    tag = " , ".join(e.text for e in element.select("a.tag"))
    all_tag.append(tag)
    
    next_page = soup.select_one('li.next>a')
    if next_page:
        next_page = base_url + next_page['href']
    else:
        pass

df = pd.DataFrame({'all_quote': all_quote,'all_author':all_author, 'all_tag': all_tag}) 
print(df)
```

Comment: How can I loop through over the pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd

base_url = "http://quotes.toscrape.com"

all_quote = []
all_author = []
all_tag = []

url = base_url

while True:
    print(url)
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")

    for element in soup.select(".quote"):
        quote = element.select_one("span.text").text
        all_quote.append(quote)

        author = element.select_one("small.author").text
        all_author.append(author)

        tag = " , ".join(e.text for e in element.select("a.tag"))
        all_tag.append(tag)

    next_page = soup.select_one("li.next>a")
    if next_page:
        url = base_url + next_page["href"]
    else:
        break

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"all_quote": all_quote, "all_author": all_author, "all_tag": all_tag}
)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", sep=";", index=None)
```

Saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that would be creating a recursive function with the parameter that you want to scrape, and updating them in each recursive call if there is next page:

```
import requests 
import bs4
import pandas as pd

base_url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com'

def scraper(url, all_quote=[], all_author=[], all_tag=[]):
    global base_url
    res = requests.get(url) 
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

    for element in soup.select('.quote'):
        quote = element.select_one('span.text').text
        all_quote.append(quote)
    
        author = element.select_one('small.author').text
        all_author.append(author)
    
        tag = " , ".join(e.text for e in element.select("a.tag"))
        all_tag.append(tag)
    
        next_page = soup.select_one('li.next>a')
        
        if next_page:
            next_page = base_url + next_page['href']
            return scraper(next_page, all_quote, all_author, all_tag)
        else:
            return [all_quote, all_author, all_tag]

data = scraper('http://quotes.toscrape.com/')
```

Once there is no next button, function returns corresponding parameters with their latest version. Now you can set `all_quote`, `all_author` and `all_tag` as below:

```
all_quote, all_author, all_tag = data
```